# Forming a new spark dataframe with some selected set of rows from a existing dataframe

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, apache-zeppelin

I have a spark data frame df with having 10^8 number of rows. I have added a column over that data frame as rowId which i want to use as a primary key.
I have done the same using the command as

df.withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())

Now from that data frame i want to select a new data frame with some selected number of rows whose index are already known to me in the form of a list.
It would be helpful for me if someone can help me to form a new data frame with the selected number of rows that are there in the list.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your use case. monotonically_increasing_id() guarantees unique ids but doesn't guarantee the ids to start at 0 or 1 or numbers to be consecutive. In my example below I've repartitioned the dataframe to show that monotonically_increasing_id() doesn't guarantee consecutive id. Anyway, assuming you have a index list you want in driver memory, you can simply join your dataframe after adding a index column.

```
//Create a sample dataframe and add rowId column. 
//Note that you may see 0,1,2 as rowIds if you dont repartition. 

val df = List("A","B","C").toDF.repartition(5).withColumn("rowId", monotonically_increasing_id())
df.show()
+-----+------------+
|value|       rowId|
+-----+------------+
|    A|  8589934592|
|    B|  8589934593|
|    C| 34359738368|
+-----+------------+

//[Option 1] to join with indexes we need to add index column to our DataFrame. Assuming your indexes align with sorted rowId
val w = org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window.orderBy("rowId")
val result = df.withColumn("index", row_number().over(w) - 1)

//here is our indexes. let convert it to Dataframe to prepare for join
val indexes = List(0, 2).toDF
//finally join
result.join(indexes, result("index") === indexes("value")).show()
+-----+-----------+-----+-----+
|value|      rowId|index|value|
+-----+-----------+-----+-----+
|    A| 8589934592|    0|    0|
|    C|34359738368|    2|    2|
+-----+-----------+-----+-----+


//[Option 2] if your list is small and can easily be sent to all workers, you can also simply filter
result.filter(result("index").isin(List(0, 2):_*)).show()
+-----+-----------+-----+
|value|      rowId|index|
+-----+-----------+-----+
|    A| 8589934592|    0|
|    C|34359738368|    2|
+-----+-----------+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks a lot can you please provide me pyspark code , because my production environment is python